# Multiline attributes with jsdom

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, screen-scraping, jsdom

is it possible to get the value of multiline attributes with jsdom (I use it with Node.js+JQuery)?

The site to scrape includes this HTML:

```
<li><a data-title="<strong>hello world
this is a test</strong>" href="example.org</strong>">A link</a></li>
```

Unfortunately, this gets parsed to

```
<li><a data-title="data-title"><strong>hello world
this is a test</strong>' href="example.org">A link</a></li>
```

and so i cannot extract the title and href attribute e.g. via JQuery: `$("a").attr("data-title")`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is a bug in `jsdom` parser. This is because it does not use a full HTML5-compliant parser. You can see such bugs are still unresolved :

1. https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/494
2. https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/482

You can try [cheerio](https://npmjs.org/package/cheerio) for scraping.

Comment: Cheerio also seems to choke on multiline attributes :-/. I think I'll switch to Mechanize.